# iphone apns in app notification alert displaying repeatedly

Tags: php, iphone

I have studied and implemented ray's these awesome tutorials on apns
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

they r working fine even in production mode i implemented them, now i wanted to display alerts type notification when app is in foreground (running) instead of bubbles, so what i did that i use nsnotification, i posted notification inside 
addMessageFromRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo updateUI:(BOOL)updateUI  method like this

```
NSMutableArray* parts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[alertValue componentsSeparatedByString:@": "]];
        message.senderName = [parts objectAtIndex:0];
        [parts removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        message.text = [parts componentsJoinedByString:@": "];
        int index = [dataModel addMessage:message];
        [MySingleton sharedMySingleton].Msender = message.senderName;
        [MySingleton sharedMySingleton].Mtext = message.text;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notificationreceived" object:nil];
```

and then i added observer in login view controler like this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(responseFromServer) name:@"TokenRecieved" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(displaynotif) name:@"Notificationreceived" object:nil];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

and

```
-(void)displaynotif
{
    NSString *msgsender = [MySingleton sharedMySingleton].Msender;
    NSString *msgtext = [MySingleton sharedMySingleton].Mtext;
    NSString *Compmsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", msgsender, msgtext];
    UIAlertView * view=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:Compmsg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [view show];
            [view release];
}
```

now i am having a problem that when first notification comes it displays only once, but when second comes it displays twice (same notification) and third came thrice and so on, i am using this php script for server side and notifications are being sent from server side through a php web form

https://github.com/sebastianborggrewe/PHP-Apple-Push-Notification-Server
i am also removing observer in dealloc.
i cant figure out whats happening, plz. guide thanx

Comment: plz. guide me, coz i am stuck here from a long time now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to debug deeper into framework that does actual connection to see what server response or at least SSL connection exception is, but my guess is that you have expired certificates - they don't last much